# Power Query - Converting whole number to text in a CUSTOM COLUMN

Tags: excel, powerbi, formula, etl, powerquery

I need to convert 3 whole number columns to text in a formula when adding a new column inside power query. I know how to do this in dax using FORMAT function but I can't make it work inside power query.

[3 columns are - click to veiw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wViO2.png)

Then below is my CUSTOM COLUMN:

```
    = Table.AddColumn(RefNo.3, "Refernce Number", each 
if Text.Length([RefNo.3]) > 1 and Text.Length([RefNo.3]) < 11  then [RefNo.3]
else if Text.Length([RefNo.2]) > 1 and Text.Length([RefNo.2]) < 11 then [RefNo.2]
else if Text.Length([RefNo.1]) > 1 and Text.Length([RefNo.1]) < 11 then [RefNo.1]
else null)
```

However, at the moment I'm getting this error:
Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type Table to type Number.
Details:
Value=[Table]
Type=[Type]

So I know I need to convert the whole number columns to text first inside the formula. Also, I had to intentionally convert those 3 columns from text to whole number previously to get rid of redundant values (so that's not an option for me to revert that). thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are any number of ways to solve this, depending on your real data.

- Just set the columns to `Type.Text` before executing your `AddColumn` function.

  - *If you do this, you would also have to check for *null* as they will cause the script, as you've written it, to fail*
  - *Or you could precede your testing with another line to replace the nulls with an empty string (""): `Table.ReplaceValue(table_name,null,"",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"RefNo", "RefNo2", "RefNo3"})`*,
- If they are all positive integers, compare the values rather than the string lengths: eg `>=0 and <10000000000`
- Construct a numeric array, and return the last value that passes the filter

```
 = Table.AddColumn(your_table_name, "Reference Number", 
      each List.Accumulate(List.Reverse(List.RemoveNulls({[RefNo],[RefNo2],[RefNo3]})),
        null,(state,current)=> if state = null then 
            let 
              x =  Text.Length(Text.From(current))
            in 
              if x > 1 and x < 11 then current else state 
        else state))
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer Ron. I guess option is for dax not power query? but can you give me and example for the type.text method please?  I couldn't pass it.

Comment: No the method was meant for Power Query, not DAX.  But in testing your method, it is apparent that, even if you do change the data type to Type.Text, your method would fail because of the *null*s

Comment: I got your point on type.text. I added it as a separate step before the table.addcolumn step, however, I'm getting "Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value null to type Logical" error now, which is as a result of null values in those 3 ref columns.

Comment: yes just saw the edited comment. that's true. it's failing because of the null values. how can I apply my logic then?! any ideas?

Comment: @Soben If you want to use your logic, you'll need to test for null or replace it before adding your column.  I'd suggest replacing it.  But I think it would probably be simpler to just use the `List.Accumulate` formula.

Comment: @Soben Instead of that long formula with all the null tests, just insert a step before to remove them with an empty string. Something like:  `Table.ReplaceValue(#"Added Custom",null,"",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"RefNo", "RefNo2", "RefNo3"}),  See my **edit**

Comment: Great, that worked for me. I'll remember the technique. Thank you very much Ron!